# DailyMotion API - Audience not always working

Tags: dailymotion-api

Using the dailymotion API, I noticed that when querying the audience on somes lives on Dailymotion Games, the result is not always true.

For example: the live with the following id xj7bck has a thousand views approximatly on the website and 0 when querying the audience through the API :
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xj7bck?fields=audience,

Any idea where it is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some users do not allow you to check the audience (there is a check box in the video settings, under the live tab), this is why the API returns 0